# Host rejected: cannot find your hostname - for one adress

Tags: postfix, configuration

We have computer with 91.221.27.120, 91.221.27.119, 91.221.27.121 and 91.221.27.118.
I set in postfix:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    warn_if_reject reject_unknown_client,
    warn_if_reject check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit
```

When I add **reject_unknown_client** I get ONLY for 91.221.27.118

```
Mar 29 09:45:31 fo-mail postfix/smtpd[6132]: NOQUEUE: reject_warning: RCPT from
unknown[91.221.27.118]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, 
[91.221.27.118]; from=<x@mydomain.pl> to=<y@mydomain.pl> proto=ESMTP 
helo=<[172.16.210.24]>
```

I writed to access

```
91.221.27.118 OK
```

It doesn't help.

Can you help me?

Comment: what is setting of `smtpd_delay_reject` and what version of Postfix you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rules in `smtpd_client_restriction` are checked in the same order as it written in the configuration directive. In your example, restrictive rule for `reject_unknown_client` is evaluating before permissive `check_client_access`. Try to change the order of those two  directives. And, of course, you should have all your clients' IP's in `access`.